# Color insertShape - Matlab

Tags: matlab

How can I change the color of the insertShape?

Code:

```
clc;
clear;
I = imread('peppers.png');
imshow(I); 
colorCode = [0.6 0.8 0]
r=20;
button = 1;
 while sum(button) <=1    
    [x,y,button] = ginput(1)
    I= insertShape(I,'FilledCircle',[x y r],'LineWidth',1, 'Color', colorCode,  'Opacity', 1);
    imshow(I); 
 end
```

Comment: If you want the same color for all circles, you should just change this line: `colorCode = [0.6 0.8 0] .* 255;`. Variable `I` will be a `uint8` with every pixel define between 0 and 255, while you define a normalized colorCode between 0 and 1, so it appears **almost** black.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should notice that when you load the image using `imread`

```
I = imread('peppers.png');
```

the data type is `uint8` that can be checked as follows:

```
>> class(I)

ans =

    'uint8'
```

In `uint8` data type, the values are in range `[0, 255]`. It means that each pixel has a value in this range. For instance:

```
>> I(10,10,1)

ans =

  uint8

   63
```

In addition, the function `insertShape` draws the shapes by overwriting pixel values. It means that it replaces the current pixel values with the `color` that has been specified in the function arguments.

Therefore, the data type of the color value has to match the image data type (e.g. both be `uint8`). So using values in range [0 1] (class `double`) will provide you with very dark color (if assumed in class `uint8`) because it is close to 0 (i.e. black).

There are two solutions to this problem

### First method - convert the color values from `double` to `uint8`

(As mentioned also by @zep in the comments)

```
colorCode = [0.6 0.8 0] * 255;
```

### Second method - convert the image to `double`

```
I = im2double(imread('peppers.png'));
```

### Result

I illustrate the result when using the second method. But there should not be any difference when employing the first method as well. Here I used `colormap` to provide me with different color vectors to be assigned to the inserted circles.

```
I = im2double(imread('peppers.png'));
imshow(I); 
colorCode = colormap*255; % gives 64 colors from the current colormap
r=20;
 for ii = 1:2:size(colorCode)
    [x,y,button] = ginput(1);
    I= insertShape(I,'FilledCircle',[x y r],'LineWidth',1, 'Color', colorCode(ii,:),  'Opacity', 0.6);
    imshow(I); 
 end
```

[image]